# Selenium running on Apache

Tags: python, apache, selenium, selenium-webdriver

"Can Selenium be run on an Apache web server?"

Update:

The solution was to use Docker and a micro services architecture on a cloud hosted virtual machine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, questions should include a specific programming issue where you expected an outcome but got something else, like an error. What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: Thanks werner, I will keep that in mind in the future.  I ended up solving my issue by using Docker and edited my question since I cant seem to delete it.